# Finding the best algorithm for nearest neighbor search in a 2D plane with moving points

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, nearest-neighbor

I am looking for an efficient way to perform nearest neighbor searches within a specified radius in a two-dimensional plane. According to Wikipedia, space-partitioning data structures, such as :

- k-d trees,
- r-trees,
- octrees,
- quadtrees,
- cover trees,
- metric trees,
- BBD trees
- locality-sensitive hashing,
- and bins,

are often used for organizing points in a multi-dimensional space and can provide O(log n) performance for search and insert operations. However, in my case, the points in the two-dimensional plane are moving at each iteration, so I need to update the tree accordingly. Rebuilding the tree from scratch at each iteration seems easier, but I would like to avoid it if possible because the points only move slightly between iterations.

I have read that k-d trees are not naturally balanced, which could be an issue in my case. R-trees, on the other hand, are better suited for storing rectangles. Bin algorithms, on the other hand, are easy to implement and provide near-linear search performance within local bins.

I am working on an autonomous agent simulation where 1,000,000 agents are rendered in the GPU, and the CPU is responsible for computing the next movement of each agent. Each agent is influenced by other agents within its line of sight, or in other words, other agents within a circular sector of angle θ and radius r. So here specific requirements for my use case:

- Search space is a 2-d plane,
- Each object is a point identified with the x,y coordinate.
- All points are frequently updated by a small factor.
- Cannot afford any O(n^2) algorithms.
- Search within a radius (circular sector)
- Search for all candidates within the search surface.

Given these considerations, what would be the best algorithms for my use case?

Comment: When asking for anything "the best", then you need to be very, ***very***, specific about your requirements, limitations and use-cases. Otherwise it will devolve into opinions.

Comment: I have also added some requirements

Comment: You can easily find literature on the problem. http://hanj.cs.illinois.edu/pdf/ssdbm04_moving.pdf https://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/Papers/soda99-moving.pdf

Comment: What do you call O(N²) ? Exhaustive search takes O(N).

Comment: @YvesDaoust N=1e6 objects, so with brute force search, during each iteration each object has iterated over all objects so : O(n^2). With a k-d tree this become O(n log n), but I need to build the tree at each iteration.

Comment: What you want is *not* nearest neighbor search, but another problem. You should fix that.

Comment: If your agents are quite uniformly spread in the domain, then the bin approach is certainly the fastest and the simplest to implement, especially on GPUs. If they are not, then you need a tree-based solution. Quadtrees are useful if you are in 2D, for a 3D domain it is octrees. Since your problem is a 2D one, octrees seems useless.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/156356/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/74881515/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could potentially solve this by doing a sort of scheduling approach. If you know that no object will move more than `d` distance in each iteration, and you want to know which objects are within `X` distance of each other on each iteration, then given the distances between all objects you know that on the next iteration the only potential pairs of objects that would change their neighbor status would be those with a distance between `X-d` and `X+d`. The iteration after that it would be `X-2d` and `X+2d` and so on.

So I'm thinking that you could do an initial distance calculation between all pairs of objects, and then based on each difference you can create an `NxN` matrix where the value in each cell is which iteration you will need to re-check their distance. Then when you re-check those during that iteration, you would update their values in this matrix for the next iteration that they need to be checked.

The only problem is whether calculating an initial `NxN` distance matrix is feasible.

Comment: Your algorithms looks nice, but each agent should update its column at each iteration. It is a O(n*n) algorithm, but distance is only computed when d is below the radius. In terms of memory, it would require a lot of RAM: M(NxN) = 1e6**2 *(2*4)/1024**4 = 7.2 GB RAM.